# Django List ID to Form

Tags: python, html, django, href

I apologies if this question has been asked, but I couldnt find anything that could help me solve a small issue.

Ive managed to create a django frame work, and created a model and a form containing data from a csv file.

Basically what im trying to do is:

Ive created a "Home Page", that looks like this(Its just basic to get the idea running):
[image]
Which contains a list of IDS(With username) from the model/form.
what I want to be able to do, is that when i click on one of the id's, for it to open my form page,which relates then to only the data of that ID... I hope that makes sense.

So lets say i create a form.html file, and id like it to show all the info in the form/model pertaining to that ID i click on.

Maybe it has something to do with Href link?

I apologies if im not too clear, but please feel free to ask me anything and il do my best to help
These are my files:

Model.py:

```
class datas(models.Model):

    country = models.CharField(_('country'),max_length=200,default='Null') 
    qs_login = models.CharField(_('qs_login'),max_length=200,default='Null') 
    Status = models.CharField(_('Status'),max_length=200,default='Null') 
    seller_id = models.CharField(_('seller_id'),max_length=200,default='Null') 
    Task_ID = models.CharField(_('Task_ID'),max_length=200,default='Null',primary_key=True) 
    associate_queue = models.CharField(_('associate_queue'),max_length=200,default='Null') 
    associate = models.CharField(_('associate'),max_length=200,default='Null') 
    metric_wk_no = models.CharField(_('associate'),max_length=200,default='Null') 
    associate_action = models.CharField(_('associate_action'),max_length=200,default='Null') 
    correct_associate_action = models.CharField(_('correct associate action'),max_length=200,default='Null') 
    Associate_Key_Driver = models.CharField(_('Associate_Key_Driver'),max_length=200,default='Null') 
    Sub_Key_driver = models.CharField(_('country'),max_length=200,default='Null') 
    Defect_Area_Associate = models.CharField(_('Defect Area Associate'),max_length=200,default='Null') 
    QA_Comments_on_Associate_Action = models.CharField(_('country'),max_length=400,default='Null') 
    Metric_name = models.CharField(_('Metric name'),max_length=200,default='Null') 


    investigator_task = models.CharField(_('investigator_task'),max_length=200,default='Null') 
    investigator_queue = models.CharField(_('investigator_queue'),max_length=200,default='Null') 
    investigator = models.CharField(_('investigator'),max_length=200,default='Null') 
    verification_action = models.CharField(_('verification_action'),max_length=200,default='Null') 
    correct_investigator_action = models.CharField(_('correct investigator action'),max_length=200,default='Null') 
    Investigator_Key_Driver = models.CharField(_('Investigator Key-Driver'),max_length=200,default='Null') 
    Defect_Area_Investigator = models.CharField(_('Defect Area Investigator'),max_length=200,default='Null') 
    QA_Comments_on_investigator_Action = models.CharField(_('QA Comments on investigator Action'),max_length=200,default='Null') 
    General_Notes = models.CharField(_('General_Notes'),max_length=200,default='Null') 
    Type_of_audit = models.CharField(_('Type of audit'),max_length=200,default='Null') 

    def __str__(self):
        return f"File: {self.country}-{self.qs_login}-{self.Status}-{self.seller_id}-{self.Task_ID}-{self.associate_queue}-{self.associate}-{self.metric_wk_no}-{self.associate_action}-{self.correct_associate_action}-{self.Associate_Key_Driver}-{self.Sub_Key_driver}-{self.Defect_Area_Associate}-{self.QA_Comments_on_Associate_Action}-{self.Metric_name}-{self.investigator_task}-{self.investigator_queue}-{self.investigator}-{self.verification_action}-{self.correct_investigator_action}-{self.Investigator_Key_Driver}-{self.Defect_Area_Investigator}-{self.QA_Comments_on_investigator_Action}-{self.General_Notes}-{self.Type_of_audit}"
    
    
    #def __str__(self):
    #    return f"{self.country}-{self.qs_login}"
    #    super().save(*args,**kwargs)
```

Views.py:

```
def homePage(request):
    model = datas.objects.filter(qs_login='nicobari')
    context = {'items': model }
    return render(request,"main/home.html",context)


def auditFormPage(response):
    model = datas.objects.filter(qs_login='nicobari')
    context = {'items': model }
    return render(response,"main/auditform.html", context)
```

This is the Home.html where the list is(As you can see i put the item.Task_ID and the item.qs_login:

```
{% for item in items %}

<div class="container-fluid">
   <li class="nav-item dropdown">
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
         <li><a class="dropdown-items" href="#">{{item.Task_ID}}-{{item.qs_login}}<br></a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</div>

{% endfor %}
```

UPDATED:

What i tried to do is create a function in the views.py page:

```
def auditFormPage(request,pk):
    model = datas.objects.filter(qs_login='nicobari')
    context = {'items': model }
    return render(request,"main/auditform.html", context)
```

Then i created a pathin the urls.py file which takes a dynamic link with the primary key:

```
path('AuditForm/<str:pk>/', views.auditFormPage, name='AuditForm'),
```

and in the dashboard/home i added a href link to the dynamic page:

```
{% for item in items %}

<div class="container-fluid">
   <li class="nav-item dropdown">
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
         <li><a class="dropdown-items" href = "{% url 'AuditForm' item.Task_ID %}">{{item.Task_ID}}-{{item.qs_login}}<br></a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</div>

{% endfor %}
```

But then i get a 404 error as page isnt found(as i guess its looking for AuditForm/str:pk/  but only found AuditForm/):

[image]

Models.py:

```
class datas(models.Model):

    country = models.CharField(_('country'),max_length=200,default='Null') 
    qs_login = models.CharField(_('qs_login'),max_length=200,default='Null') 
    Status = models.CharField(_('Status'),max_length=200,default='Null') 
    seller_id = models.CharField(_('seller_id'),max_length=200,default='Null') 
    Task_ID = models.CharField(_('Task_ID'),max_length=200,default='Null',primary_key=True) 
    associate_queue = models.CharField(_('associate_queue'),max_length=200,default='Null') 
    associate = models.CharField(_('associate'),max_length=200,default='Null') 
    metric_wk_no = models.CharField(_('associate'),max_length=200,default='Null') 
    associate_action = models.CharField(_('associate_action'),max_length=200,default='Null') 
    correct_associate_action = models.CharField(_('correct associate action'),max_length=200,default='Null') 
    Associate_Key_Driver = models.CharField(_('Associate_Key_Driver'),max_length=200,default='Null') 
    Sub_Key_driver = models.CharField(_('country'),max_length=200,default='Null') 
    Defect_Area_Associate = models.CharField(_('Defect Area Associate'),max_length=200,default='Null') 
    QA_Comments_on_Associate_Action = models.CharField(_('country'),max_length=400,default='Null') 
    Metric_name = models.CharField(_('Metric name'),max_length=200,default='Null') 


    investigator_task = models.CharField(_('investigator_task'),max_length=200,default='Null') 
    investigator_queue = models.CharField(_('investigator_queue'),max_length=200,default='Null') 
    investigator = models.CharField(_('investigator'),max_length=200,default='Null') 
    verification_action = models.CharField(_('verification_action'),max_length=200,default='Null') 
    correct_investigator_action = models.CharField(_('correct investigator action'),max_length=200,default='Null') 
    Investigator_Key_Driver = models.CharField(_('Investigator Key-Driver'),max_length=200,default='Null') 
    Defect_Area_Investigator = models.CharField(_('Defect Area Investigator'),max_length=200,default='Null') 
    QA_Comments_on_investigator_Action = models.CharField(_('QA Comments on investigator Action'),max_length=200,default='Null') 
    General_Notes = models.CharField(_('General_Notes'),max_length=200,default='Null') 
    Type_of_audit = models.CharField(_('Type of audit'),max_length=200,default='Null') 

    def __str__(self):
        return f"File: {self.country}-{self.qs_login}-{self.Status}-{self.seller_id}-{self.Task_ID}-{self.associate_queue}-{self.associate}-{self.metric_wk_no}-{self.associate_action}-{self.correct_associate_action}-{self.Associate_Key_Driver}-{self.Sub_Key_driver}-{self.Defect_Area_Associate}-{self.QA_Comments_on_Associate_Action}-{self.Metric_name}-{self.investigator_task}-{self.investigator_queue}-{self.investigator}-{self.verification_action}-{self.correct_investigator_action}-{self.Investigator_Key_Driver}-{self.Defect_Area_Investigator}-{self.QA_Comments_on_investigator_Action}-{self.General_Notes}-{self.Type_of_audit}"
```

THANKS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated answer**

Since you have `Task_ID` been set `primary_key=True`.

```
path('AuditForm/<str:pk>/', views.auditFormPage, name='AuditForm'),
```

In order to retrieve a specific object from the model list using that `pk` passed to the `auditFormPage` view, you can use the `get` method on the model list.

```
def auditFormPage(request, pk):
    data= datas.objects.get(Task_ID=pk)
    context = {'data': data}
    return render(request,"main/auditform.html", context)
```

This will match back `<a class="dropdown-items" href = "{% url 'AuditForm' item.Task_ID %}">{{item.Task_ID}}-{{item.qs_login}}<br></a>`

**OR**

Try retrieving the object not by the primary key but by the id itself...

```
path('AuditForm/<int:id>/', views.auditFormPage, name='AuditForm'),
```

*views.py*

```
def auditFormPage(request, id):
    data= datas.objects.get(id=id)
    context = {'data': data}
    return render(request,"main/auditform.html", context)
```

*within the html*

```
`<a class="dropdown-items" href ="{% url 'AuditForm' item.id %}">{{item.Task_ID}}-{{item.qs_login}}<br></a>`
```

That should take you to the page.

Comment: If it did solve your problem bro, then maybe you should accept this as the answer to help those who might have the same problem. :-)

Comment: OHH brother il give you a 5 star if you help me, and thank you very much for taking your time to help me here, i guess not all heroes wear capes

Comment: So when i apply what you said, on the Home page i get this following error: NoReverseMatch at /Home/
Reverse for 'AuditForm' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['AuditForm/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$']
And on the auditform page i get this error: Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/AuditForm/

Comment: It is important to note that my primary key is consisted of int and str like the following: A2H3CPIC92GV0S. I have tried both but if i use"{% url 'AuditForm' item.pk %}" and then on the URL.py i use str instead of int, i am able to access the home page, but get the 404 error on the auditform page

Comment: Do i need to add anything on the auditform.html?

Comment: sorry for all the questions brother. Im soo close but so far away, and your my only saviour

Comment: I made those changes, which makes sense, but unfortunately im still getting the 404 error :( , im sorry for all the back and forth.

Comment: Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/AuditForm/
Using the URLconf defined in auditor.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
Home/ [name='Home']
AuditForm/<str:pk>/ [name='AuditForm']
register/ [name='Register']
Login/ [name='Login']
^static/(?P<path>.*)$
settings/
^media/(?P<path>.*)$
The current path, AuditForm/, didn’t match any of these.

Comment: Try using the id on the object instead... Give it another try. This will be fixed today! See the updated answer.

Comment: I tried both steps, maybe it has something to do with how i created my model? i just updated it in the question

Comment: im just messing with it now to see if i can get it running

Comment: IT WORKSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS. I LOVE YOU

Comment: I'm glad it worked! :-D Remember to click the tick icon to accept the answer! :-D

Comment: I believe I did. Let me know if i didnt

Comment: No you haven't bro. What you did you clicked the one that says "This answer is useful", you should click the one that says "Accept this answer if it solved your problem or was the most helpful in finding your your solution. " It looks like this `✔`

Comment: AHHHHHH, this whole time i thought that was the way to do it. I believe to have done it! thank you brooo